# setup unable to find zope

Tags: python, zope, crossbar

hello I am unable to install crossbar.io due to a zope error. here is the env details

```
ENV:

Python 3.11.6 (main, Oct 16 2023, 14:39:12) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.


uname -a
Darwin <SR_NO> 22.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: Fri Sep 15 13:39:52 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.141.3.700.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Processing dependencies for crossbar==23.1.2
Searching for zope-interface>=5
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/zope-interface/
/Users/<username>/workspace/new-python/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:123: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning:  is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
No local packages or working download links found for zope-interface>=5
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('zope-interface>=5')

(venv) ➜  crossbar git:(master) pip freeze | grep zope
zope.interface==6.1
```

zope is installed correctly but setup is failing to recognize the install

Comment: Does the package support your Python version?